# Phpspec No calls have been made that match

Tags: php, bdd, phpspec

I'm struggling with `phpspec` and `No calls have been made that match` while the call was actually made. Here is the code so far:

```
    function it_imports_social_feeds(
        ContainerInterface $container,
        FacebookManagerFactory $managerFactory,
        FacebookConnector $facebookConnector,
        FacebookMapper $facebookMapper,
        EzContent $ezContent,
        Collection $feed,
        Content $content
    )
    {
        $chainProfiles = [];


        $container->getParameter('someParam1')->willReturn($chainProfiles);
        $container->get('someParam2')
            ->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($managerFactory);

        $managerFactory->createFacebookConnector(Argument::type('string'))->willReturn($facebookConnector);
        $facebookConnector->getFeed()->shouldBeCalled();

        $facebookMapper->getData()->willReturn($feed);


        $container->getParameter('someParam3')->shouldBeCalled();
        $container->getParameter('someParam4')->shouldBeCalled();

        // these 2 call are issue
        $ezContent->save(Argument::type('array'), Argument::any(), Argument::any())->willReturn($content)->shouldBeCalled();
        $ezContent->updatePublishedDate(Argument::type('string'), $content)->shouldBeCalled();

        $this->importFeeds();

    }
```

And implemented class method:

```
public function importFeeds()
{
    $socialChainsProfiles = $this->container->getParameter('mrkisha_social_feed_profiles');

    foreach($socialChainsProfiles as $socialMedia => $chainsProfiles) {

        foreach($chainsProfiles as $chain => $chainsProfile) {
            $fbConnector = $this->container
                ->get("social.feed.facebook.factory")
                ->createFacebookConnector($chainsProfile);

            $fbMapper = new FacebookMapper($fbConnector);

            $fbData = $fbMapper->getData();

            $contentTypeIdentifier = $this->container->getParameter('social_feed_content_type_identifier');
            $folderId = $this->container->getParameter('social_feed_folder_ids')[$chain];

            $sortedData = $fbData->sortByDesc('publishedAt')->values()->all();

            foreach ($sortedData as $item) {
                $item['socialFeed'] = $socialMedia;
                $publishedDate = $item['publishedAt'];

                unset($item['publishedAt']);

                // These 2 calls withing loop phpspec does not see
                $content = $this->ezContent->save($item, $contentTypeIdentifier, $folderId);

                $this->ezContent->updatePublishedDate($publishedDate, $content);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm beginner in testing and the resources online for phpspec are almost non existent, any help is much appreciated regarding what concept am I missing here and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are container calls parameters correct? because, if so, the calls causing issues are them. Please, post message error also.

Comment: The error `No calls have been made that match` is related to $ezContent->save havent made, while in implementation is called.

One thing just came to my mind, do I have to provide array parameters for each of those for loops in order to reach the 3rd loop?

Comment: The implementation of your code isn't the same of what  I read in the spec file. If you have modified it, you should modify the code as well, otherwise you should report real spec class. If code and class are actually what you have, your spec file is totally wrong.

Comment: the only difference in spec file and here in spec code are parameters `someParam1..4` where i call exact parameters that I have in implementation.

Comment: So why this changes? Please, modify code or spec accordly, otherwise this has no sense at all